# Editing default manually created R package pdf documentation

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I have the problem following! Is there any possibility to edit manually created package documentation by

```
detools::build_manual()
```

? I want to add new section and subsections and also include them into table of contents. So instead of having 'R topics documented' I want to have for example 'Section 1',

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect this is the wrong document for your purpose. You should probably create a vignette instead.

Comment: You can get the LaTeX source code of the pdf but you it is not possible to use a custom pdf for the documentation.

Comment: How can I get LaTeX source code of my documentation ?